# Grab multiselect values from a form NodeJS MySQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, crud

I am trying to fetch multi-select values from a form.

**JS Code**

```
router.post('/profile', (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.body.name);
})
```

**HTML /profile**

```
<div class="form-group" method="POST">
    <br>
    <select class="form-control multiselect" multiple="multiple">
    {{#team}}
        <option value="{{name}}" name="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
    {{/team}}
    </select>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Update Members<i class="icon-circle-right2 ml-2"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

On submitting I am not able to log the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues within your code.

- First of all, since you are passing a variable as a name `name="{{name}}"`, I assume that variable has a value equal to `name[]`, notice you need to add array brackets to send multiple values for the same key.
- Also `method="POST"` attribute should be added to form tag, not div.

In the end, your code should be similar to the code below:

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <br>
        <select class="form-control multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="name[]">
        {{#team}}
            <option value="{{name}}" >{{name}}</option>
        {{/team}}
        </select>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Update Members<i class="icon-circle-right2 ml-2"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It's not returning any value.
Output: {}